# Load QMainWindow as tab within another main window

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a script which creates a pyqt GUI that controls a device.
It's a class which inherits from QMainWindow, which I run like this:

```
qtCreatorFile = "GuiTemplate.ui" #.ui file created with QT Designer
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("GuiGuiTemplate.ui")[0]
 
class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)

   #def a bunch of methods and signals to connect them to...


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MyApp()
  window.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I now wish to control multiple devices, and my goal would be to create a new tab for every device that I connect, where the contents of the tabs are just copies of this main window.

So far I've tried to simply import the class above into a new script, and add the class as a tab:

```
from originalGuiScript import MyApp

#initialization code here
  self.tabs = QTabWidget()
  self.tabs.addTab(MyApp,"Tab 1")
```

but this yields the following error:

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
> addTab(self, QWidget, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'
> addTab(self, QWidget, QIcon, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sip.wrappertype'

I feel like there should be an easy way to make this work, but none of my searching has turned up anything useful thus far.

Comment: Typo: you need to create an instance, right now you're using a class `self.tabs.addTab(MyApp(),"Tab 1")`. Note that: 1. QMainWindow is supposed to be used as a top level window (hence the name), not a child widget; you should use QWidget instead; 2. There's no point in calling the `__init__` of `Ui_MainWindow` (since it does nothing). Remove *both* `__init__` calls and just do `super().__init__()` instead.

Comment: Arg! that's embarrassing... It immediately worked once I added the parentheses, thanks!

I was able to implement your second note, but if I replace QMainWindow with QWidget as my inheritance class, I run into an AttributeError once I call `self.setupUi(self)`:

"'MyApp' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'"

It seems like everything is working as expected if I just leave the inheritance as is though. Is that likely to cause problems down the line?

Comment: That's because you are still using the previous UI file, which is a QMainWindow, while you need a QWidget based UI: create a *new* "Widget" in Designer, recreate the UI you had in that main window (you can use drag and drop), and save as the new UI file, which will you will then use instead of the previous one. While it's not strictly "forbidden" to use a QMainWindow as a child widget, it's discouraged and unnecessary: their implementation is more complex than a standard QWidget and is usually unnecessary, unless you need its features *as those of a child widget*; those features include: ->

Comment: -> a menu bar (which you can still add to the main widget layout using `layout.setMenuBar()`), a status bar (which can be implemented easily by overriding the widget's `event()`) and dock widgets or toolbars (which are normally part of the top level window, not its children). Most of the times, you only need those aspects as the actual *main* window, and even if you need to change their aspect or behavior based on the currently shown widget, you can still do that by properly connecting to the `currentChanged` signal of the tab widget.